# find a text in elements of list if exists append it to a new list

Tags: python, list, count, element, string-search

```
list = ['0-0-0-0-0-4-0', '0-0-0-1-0-4-2', '0-0-3-0-0-80-0', '0-0-3-1-0-81-0', '0-0-3-0-0-82-0']

appendlist = ['0-0-3-0']
```

search for first 7 digit of element like that 0-0-3-0 occurance 2 times

'**0-0-3-0-0**-80-0', '**0-0-3-0-0**-82-0' then if 11th-12th digits of elements(80-82) different code will append the first 7 digit like appendlist = ['0-0-3-0']

I can't use any library import !!! only loops

```
info =['0-0-0-0-0-4-0', '0-0-0-1-0-4-2', '0-0-3-0-0-80-0', '0-0-3-1-0-81-0', '0-0-3-0-0-82-0']

infolist = []

for n in info
    if info.count(n[0:7]) > 1
        if n not in infolist
            infolist.append(n)
        end
    end
end

Print(infolist)
```

I tried this but list output is empty

I tried count method

Comment: This is not Python code you've shown us. It looks a bit more like Ruby, but it isn't that either.

Comment: It would be python if you got rid of the `end` lines and put `:` at the end of the `for` and `if` lines.

Comment: This Python Based language Hsl I need only loops. I can solve my problem if you help me about algorithm. Elements are string and I want to count occurrences like i[0:7] but I m getting empty list. So why this happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`info.count()` looks for exact matches, not substrings. You need to count the number of items that start with `n[0:7]`. That can be done with the `sum()` function.

You can prevent duplicates by making `infolist` a set rather than a list. If you need a list, you can turn it into a list at the end.

```
infolist = set()

for n in info:
    if sum(item.startswith(n[0:7]) for item in info) > 1:
        infolist.add(n)

infolist = list(infolist)
```

Comment: It's a shame the OP can't import `collections.Counter`. `[k for k, v in Counter(x[0:7] for x in list).items() if v > 1]`

Comment: It says item is not defined 

Comment: I just tested it and it works without error.